# Headings inside table cells don't appear in Navigation pane: workaround?

Tags: ms-word

I have a long table.  Not realizing that headings inserted inside a table don't appear in the Outline View or the Navigation Pane (See Blom's answer to http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/headings-do-not-appear-in-navigation-pane/c3ff186f-8363-47e2-9f46-8f2cf83d78b4), I put a bunch of Heading 1 and Heading 2 headings inside my table.  Now I'm having trouble jumping around inside my document.

The brute force approach that has occurred to me is to split the table after every heading, and take the heading out of the table.

Any other ideas?

MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue and [Stefan Blom's answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/headings-do-not-appear-in-navigation-pane/c3ff186f-8363-47e2-9f46-8f2cf83d78b4) still holds:

> It is a known limitation in Word that headings inside table cells won't appear in the Navigation pane. For what it's worth, the same thing applies to the predecessor of the Navigation pane, the so-called Document Map, in older versions of Word.
>   As you have noticed, Word properly adds headings inside a table to the TOC, fortunately.

If you want the headings to appear in the navigation pane you have to place them outside of tables, i.e. your suggested approach is the way to go.

If you still want the heading to appear like it is part of the table you can simulate that by adding a paragraph border around your heading. **(Note: This still does not work if it is in a table cell. You must be outside the table cell.)**

Comment: Thank you so much, I will bite the bullet, and reformat manually.  Live and learn!  (This particular document is just a huge repository of notes for my own work process, so I don't need the paragraph border this time, but maybe in future!)  (I will wait to accept on the tiny off chance someone will have a miraculous alternative to suggest.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found useful this alternative:

1. Select desired text inside the table and insert Bookmarks  from Insert > Bookmarks:
   [image: Insert bookmark]
2. Type a Name and add the bookmark :

[image: Inset Bookmark Name]

3. Use Bookmark Panel (CTRL+SHIFT+F5) or "Go To" command to navigate inside the document

Answer (score 0):

In my case, headings weren't shown because I mixed heading and body text. Example(black text: heading):

**OR operator** Displays records if any condition is TRUE

So I solved it putting the body text below

**OR operator**
Displays records if any condition is TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I realised this pain also and not wanting to lose my beautiful formatting and table layout, I added the necessary HEADINGS above each table in white text, so they didn't show in my doc, but displayed in my Navigation Pane.
Of course if some jackass deletes a Heading line it'll all go topsy turvy